# Two-dimensional Arrays (matrices) in C

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm writing code that checks if m2 matrix is a sub-matrix of m1.

Currently I have created a method that receives matrix m1 and matrix m2 of fixed size.
First of all I check that m1 is larger than m2 otherwise m2 cannot be a sub-matrix of m1. Then I have the variable result which indicates 1 if m2 is sub-matrix, or indicates 0 if it is not.

I can't find the right technique to check this thing out. I have started scanning the rows and columns of the arrays, but I don't know how to correctly structure the code to verify it correctly.

This is the code:

```
void CheckSubMatrix (int rows, int cols, int m1[][cols], int m2[2][2]){
     int rowsm2=2;
     int colsm2=2;
     int result=1;
     
     if(rows >= rowsm2 && cols >= colsm2){
              for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
                       for(int j=0; j<cols; j++){
                                if(m1[i][j] != m2[i][j]
                                         result=0;
                       }
              }
     } else {
     result = 0;


     if (result)
     printf("Is a Sub-Matrix");
     else
     printf("Is not a Sub-Matrix");
```

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to understand how two-dimensional arrays and matrices work in order to understand even the simplest one-dimensional arrays.

Thanks to those who will help me.

Note:

- example of sub-matrix: [image](http://data:image/png;base64,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)

[image: examples of sub-matrix]

EDIT:
I know that the code `if(m1[i][j] != m2[i][j] result=0;` doesn't work, because the program will take the values of i and j at the last for loop. But I just didn't know how to be able to implement it.

Comment: The first thing you need to learn (IMO) is that C doesn't really have "multi-dimensional" arrays. What is commonly called a "2D" array or a matrix is an array *of arrays*. It's simply an array whose elements are in turn arrays.

Comment: It would be simpler to initialize `int result = 0;` and change it to `1` when a matching sub-matrix is found.

Comment: Please define *in your question* what you consider as a sub-matrix: (a) If m2 appears in m1 *at any position*? Or (b) if m1[0..1][1..1] matches m2? Your code `if(m1[i][j] != m2[i][j])` would only compare identical positions in both arrays as in (b), but it would result in an out-of-bounds access to m2 if m1 is larger than m2. BTW: Your image link doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: That is a useless comment. Even if it were true, it has no relevance to this question; `m1[i][j]` does exactly what OP wants and needs. But it is not true. When something is declared as an array of arrays, it is in fact a two-dimensional array, behaves as a two-dimensional array, and serves as a two-dimensional array. The fact it is implemented via multiple steps instead of as a single built-in feature in no way negates the fact the end result is a multidimensional array.

Comment: @Bodo I edited the question with a new image.

Comment: Try using four nested loops. The two outer loops iterate through possible positions of the top left corner of the submatrix in `m1`. The two inner loops compare the submatrix with `m2`.

Comment: The images of the sample matrices should be plain text in the question — treat it as 'code'.

Answer (score 2):

Making judicious use of functions makes the code easier, I think.  Using VLA notation for all array arguments means that the code can handle your three test cases, plus a couple of extras with non-square matrices. (The use of `void CheckSubMatrix (int rows, int cols, int m1[][cols], int m2[2][2]){` in the code in the question prevents any of the sample tests from working; that checking function only accepts 2x2 sub-matrices).  Since the code is only checking the matrices, the matrices should be specified with the `const` qualifier.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

static int SubMatrixHere(int r, int c,
                         int rows1, int cols1, const int m1[rows1][cols1],
                         int rows2, int cols2, const int m2[rows2][cols2])
{
    assert(r + rows2 <= rows1 && c + cols2 <= cols1);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols2; j++)
        {
            if (m1[r+i][c+j] != m2[i][j])
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

static int CheckSubMatrix(int rows1, int cols1, const int m1[rows1][cols1],
                          int rows2, int cols2, const int m2[rows2][cols2])
{
    if (rows1 < rows2 || cols1 < cols2)
        return 0;

    int ub_rows = rows1 - rows2 + 1;
    int ub_cols = cols1 - cols2 + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < ub_rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ub_cols; j++)
        {
            /* The test for m1[i][j] == m2[0][0] is a big saving */
            if (m1[i][j] == m2[0][0] &&
                SubMatrixHere(i, j, rows1, cols1, m1, rows2, cols2, m2))
                return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

static void dump_matrix(const char *tag, int rows, int cols, const int matrix[rows][cols])
{
    printf("%s (%dx%d):\n", tag, rows, cols);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        const char *pad = "";
        int length = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            length += printf("%s%d", pad, matrix[i][j]);
            if (length > 60)
            {
                putchar('\n');
                length = 0;
                pad = "";
            }
            else
                pad = ", ";
        }
        if (length > 0)
            putchar('\n');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

static void test_submatrix(const char *t1, int r1, int c1, const int m1[r1][c1],
                           const char *t2, int r2, int c2, const int m2[r2][c2])
{
    dump_matrix(t1, r1, c1, m1);
    dump_matrix(t2, r2, c2, m2);
    if (CheckSubMatrix(r1, c1, m1, r2, c2, m2))
        printf("%s is a sub-matrix of %s\n", t2, t1);
    else
        printf("%s is not a sub-matrix of %s\n", t2, t1);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    int m1[4][4] =
    {
        { 1, 4, 6, 8 },
        { 2, 5, 7, 0 },
        { 3, 6, 9, 0 },
        { 4, 5, 8, 1 },
    };
    int m2[3][3] =
    {
        { 1, 4, 6 },
        { 2, 5, 7 },
        { 3, 6, 9 },
    };
    int m3[3][3] =
    {
        { 5, 7, 0 },
        { 6, 9, 0 },
        { 5, 8, 1 },
    };
    int m4[3][3] =
    {
        { 1, 4, 6 },
        { 2, 5, 7 },
        { 3, 6, 2 },
    };

    test_submatrix("m1", 4, 4, m1, "m2", 3, 3, m2);
    test_submatrix("m1", 4, 4, m1, "m3", 3, 3, m3);
    test_submatrix("m1", 4, 4, m1, "m4", 3, 3, m4);

    const int m5[6][4] =
    {
        { 68, 59, 61, 70 },
        { 65, 86, 44,  9 },
        { 23, 55, 24, 31 },
        { 51, 21, 10, 99 },
        { 19, 99, 43, 95 },
        { 64, 25, 79, 67 },
    };

    const int m6[2][3] =
    {
        { 55, 24, 31 },
        { 21, 10, 99 },
    };

    const int m7[4][2] =
    {
        { 44,  9 },
        { 24, 31 },
        { 10, 99 },
        { 43, 96 },
    };
    test_submatrix("m5", 6, 4, m5, "m6", 2, 3, m6);
    test_submatrix("m5", 6, 4, m5, "m7", 4, 2, m7);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
m1 (4x4):
1, 4, 6, 8
2, 5, 7, 0
3, 6, 9, 0
4, 5, 8, 1

m2 (3x3):
1, 4, 6
2, 5, 7
3, 6, 9

m2 is a sub-matrix of m1

m1 (4x4):
1, 4, 6, 8
2, 5, 7, 0
3, 6, 9, 0
4, 5, 8, 1

m3 (3x3):
5, 7, 0
6, 9, 0
5, 8, 1

m3 is a sub-matrix of m1

m1 (4x4):
1, 4, 6, 8
2, 5, 7, 0
3, 6, 9, 0
4, 5, 8, 1

m4 (3x3):
1, 4, 6
2, 5, 7
3, 6, 2

m4 is not a sub-matrix of m1

m5 (6x4):
68, 59, 61, 70
65, 86, 44, 9
23, 55, 24, 31
51, 21, 10, 99
19, 99, 43, 95
64, 25, 79, 67

m6 (2x3):
55, 24, 31
21, 10, 99

m6 is a sub-matrix of m5

m5 (6x4):
68, 59, 61, 70
65, 86, 44, 9
23, 55, 24, 31
51, 21, 10, 99
19, 99, 43, 95
64, 25, 79, 67

m7 (4x2):
44, 9
24, 31
10, 99
43, 96

m7 is not a sub-matrix of m5
```

Comment: Why not `size_t` instead of `int`?

Comment: Both `int` and `size_t` work fine for this code; I didn't change it as it wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the correct types for sizes (`size_t`)
2. You need more loops

```
int issubmatrix(size_t hrows, size_t hcols, int (*haystack)[hcols],
                size_t nrows, size_t ncols, int (*needle)[ncols])
{
    int itis = 0;
    int exitloop = 0;

    if(haystack && needle && ncols <= hcols && nrows <= hrows)
    {
        for(size_t start_row = 0; start_row <= hrows - nrows; start_row++)
        {
            for(size_t start_col = 0; start_col <= hcols - ncols; start_col++)
            {
                exitloop = 0;
                for(size_t row = 0; row < nrows; row++)
                {
                    for(size_t col = 0; col < ncols; col++)
                    {
                        if(haystack[start_row + row][start_col + col] != needle[row][col])
                        {
                            exitloop = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                        if(exitloop) break;
                    }
                    if(exitloop) break;
                }
                if(!exitloop) itis = 1;
            }
            if(itis) break;
        }
    }
    return itis;
}


int main(void)
{
    int haystack[][4] = {
        {1,4,6,8},
        {2,5,7,0},
        {3,6,9,0},
        {4,5,8,1},
    };
    int needle1[][3] =
    {
        {1,4,6},
        {2,5,7},
        {3,6,9},
    };

    int needle2[][3] =
    {
        {5,7,0},
        {6,9,0},
        {5,8,1},
    };

    int needle3[][3] =
    {
        {1,4,6},
        {2,5,7},
        {3,6,2},
    };

    printf("%d\n", issubmatrix(4,4, haystack, 3,3, needle1));
    printf("%d\n", issubmatrix(4,4, haystack, 3,3, needle2));
    printf("%d\n", issubmatrix(4,4, haystack, 3,3, needle3));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/YTMfWP8ca

Comment: Any comment silent DV-ter?